# Cannot deploy a custom class mediator on WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-integrator

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: samples.mediators.SimpleClassMediator cannot be found by synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:100)
... 27 more

Class mediator is packaged within the composite application and deployed the .car file

was trying to deploy Export project as Deployable Archive but didn't work.

Comment: complete source code: https://github.com/GayanM/Healthcare

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue after restarting the Integration Studio. Putting below links for benefit of others.

[1] https://oneiam.medium.com/custom-class-mediator-with-wso2-micro-integrator-4-2-0-part-01-5ac723945acc

[2]https://oneiam.medium.com/custom-class-mediator-with-wso2-micro-integrator-4-2-0-part-02-58cd60c1c7ef